# Problems in using Autodesk forge with mapbox

Tags: three.js, mapbox, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, mapbox-gl

Now I am using the Autodesk forge to render the 3D buildings on the website.
I am using React.js as a front-end framework.
Things were going well but one thing is really difficult to implement.
My goal is on the forge view, render the 3D building on the map(I gonna use Mapbox API).
So the result might be the [3D building on Map in forge view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUNZf.png) same as the image below.
But I am not sure if is this possible or not.
So if anybody has experience in using Autodesk forge and Mapbox, please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by rendering the 3d maps on the forge viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help here...

Here's two quick options, depending on whether you need Mapbox's GIS review tools or you need Autodesk's AEC review tools...
, Mapbox renderer is more important, or if Forge-Viewer is more important...

1. (more GIS tools) Use Mapbox Renderer, pull in glTF of your Revit/Naviworks/AutoCad model via this code/demo: https://github.com/wallabyway/mapboxRevit

   demo video: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/440241/65015225-beaaa980-d8d5-11e9-94ce-4876c628ac09.gif
2. (more AEC tools) Use Forge-Viewer Renderer, and add a mapbox quad-tile layer underneath the 3D model inside Forge-Viewer:  Like this
   https://gist.github.com/wallabyway/4503609e84a2b612b27138abba8aa3b7

   demo video: https://youtu.be/9kVHlTV8wHw

Let me know if that helps ;-)[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And is this possible to merge the mapbox renderer and the forge renderer?

Comment: No, they are two separate renderers, at the moment.